# Jersey REST client - multipart creation - not from File object

Tags: java, rest, jersey, client, multipart

I guess there is no other way for creating a FileDateBodyPart than providing a File object:

```
public FileDataBodyPart(String name, File fileEntity)
```

But in my case what I have is a byte[] and I don't want to convert it to a file and store on a filesystem.

Is there any other way of generating a multipart (while uploading a file) from an array of byte, inputstream... in the worst case using other client library?

UPDATE:
Here is the working code (but I want to use byte[] instead of File):

```
FileDataBodyPart filePart = new FileDataBodyPart("attachment", new File("C:/TEMP/test.txt"));
MultiPart multipart = new FormDataMultiPart().bodyPart(filePart);
Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = webTarget.request().accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
Response response = invocationBuilder
        .buildPost(Entity.entity(multipart, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA))
        .invoke();
```

Comment: The question is rather unclear. Show some more code. What are your intentions?

Comment: Question is updated.

Answer (score 6):

`FileDataBodyPart` is just a convenience class. It is not the only type you can use to create a body part. If you look at the docs for `FormDataMultuPart.bodyPart()`, you'll see that it takes as an argument a `BodyPart`. Check out the [Javadocs](https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest/jersey/index.html) (search for it; can't find direct link). If you look for `BodyPart` and traverse the hierarchy, there are a few classes the extend from `BodyPart`, like `FormDataBodyPart` (the most generic) and also `StreamDataBodyPart`. You could use either.

If you have an `InputStream`, the easiest way is to use the `StreamDataBodyPart`. See the javadoc, it has overloaded constructors.

If you MUST use a `byte[]`, then you can just use the more generic `FormDataBodyPart`

```
byte[] bytes = "HelloWorld".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
FormDataContentDisposition fdcd = FormDataContentDisposition.name("test")
        .fileName("hello.txt").build();
FormDataBodyPart bodyPart = new FormDataBodyPart(fdcd, bytes, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE);
MultiPart multiPart = new FormDataMultiPart().bodyPart(bodyPart);
```

Parts should have a `Content-Disposition` header which give a little information about the part, so the server can handle it properly. The `FileDataBodyPart` and `StreamDataBodyPart` would handle the creation of the `FormDataContentDisposition` internally, that's why they are *convenience* classes.

Comment: That's my choice. Thank you.

Comment: Somehow the `StreamDataBodyPart` did not work for me (no exception, but no data on server side), but creating a `FormDataBodyPart` did work!

Answer (score 4):

There's no other way for `FileDataBodyPart` to not accept a file.

As a workaround, you might want to create a temporary file and delete it once the JVM exits:

```
byte[] bytes = {1, 2, 3};

File tempFile = File.createTempFile("filename", null);
tempFile.deleteOnExit();

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
fos.write(bytes);
fos.close();

FileDataBodyPart filePart = new FileDataBodyPart("attachment", tempFile);
```

Comment: Yes, that could be an option. Thanks.